# Can not change permissions of files/directories in a chrooted filesystem

Tags: permissions, files, squashfs

I am using **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bits** to chroot into a just extracted to my harddrive (with `unsquashfs`) Squash File System from a Kali Linux v1.0.5 32 bits pendrive for customizations:

```
luis@Fujur:$ sudo chroot /media/Datos/Temporal/squashfs/modificando
root@Fujur:/# ls
0    boot  etc   initrd.img  media  opt   root  sbin     srv  tmp  var
bin  dev   home  lib         mnt    proc  run   selinux  sys  usr  vmlinuz
```

I have been able to modify files (`/etc/rc.local`, add users with `adduser` and some other minor changes to the extracted filesystem), but the created new users have this problem:

```
root@Fujur:/# ls /home -la
total 8
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:45 .
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 4096 sep  5  2013 ..
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 4096 mar 24 00:29 luis
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:45 potato
```

as you can see, **the owner is "root", and the group is "plugdev"**, when both should be the same name of the user account (luis/potato in this example).
Knowing **why this happen** should be fine, but I think I could solve it if I could **change file/directory permissions**, but I can not neither:

```
root@Fujur:/tmp# cd /home/
root@Fujur:/home# ls -la
total 8
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:45 .
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 4096 sep  5  2013 ..
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 4096 mar 24 00:29 luis
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:45 potato
root@Fujur:/home# chown potato potato
root@Fujur:/home# ls -la
total 8
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:45 .
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 4096 sep  5  2013 ..
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 4096 mar 24 00:29 luis
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:45 potato
```

and even on `/temp` there is no chance:

```
root@Fujur:/# cd /tmp
root@Fujur:/tmp# ls -la
total 4
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:52 .
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 4096 sep  5  2013 ..
root@Fujur:/tmp# mkdir test
root@Fujur:/tmp# ls -la
total 4
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:57 .
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 4096 sep  5  2013 ..
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:57 test
root@Fujur:/tmp# chmod a+x test
root@Fujur:/tmp# ls -la
total 4
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:57 .
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 4096 sep  5  2013 ..
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:57 test
root@Fujur:/tmp# chmod a-x test
root@Fujur:/tmp# ls -la
total 4
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:57 .
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 4096 sep  5  2013 ..
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    0 mar 24 22:57 test
```

It is such a strange thing: I can make directories and files, even editing files, but not changing permissions.
Maybe I have not *chrooted* correctly? When I *chroot` into a partition to restore GRUB I do:

```
$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
```

prior to `chroot`, but I think this is not the case.
I believe I could be misusing the `chroot` command. Any ideas, please?

ADDED: this is the result of `mount`.
Outside (before) chroot:

```
root@Fujur:/# mount
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda7 on /media/Datos type fuseblk (rw)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /var/lib/lightdm/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=lightdm)
```

Inside (after) chroot:

```
root@Fujur:/# mount
warning: failed to read mtab
```

EDIT: Just tested and I have the same problem outside `chroot`, this is: **without chrooting**. I can not change file/directories permissions. Still there are no errors, but the changes are not made.

Comment: Could you give us the output of `mount` outside and inside the chroot, please?

Comment: Sure, @n.st, here you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

> /dev/sda7 on /media/Datos type fuseblk (rw)

from `mount`'s output tells you that `/media/Datos` is an NTFS partition (`type fuseblk`).

NTFS cannot store ownership and permissions in the same way Linux/Unix filesystems like ext{2..4} can. That's why you can set ownership/permissions but they do not persist.

You'll need to switch to a "proper" filesystem (e.g. ext4) for that.

Comment: Upsss... you are right, @n.st. I think I don't have any **EXT partition** available right now, so I will try with a **loop device** in a virtual disk file of enough size. Thanks you.